# spinner value updation by another spinner which uses autocomplete text view not working

Tags: android, android-spinner, autocompletetextview

I have two spinners  in which the first spinner uses autocomplete textview , when first spinner item is selected in normal way without using autocomplete text view the second spinner loads the corresponding value according to the first spinners selection. My issue is that when autocomplete textview is used for selecting first spinner value the second spinner is not loaded with the values according to first spinners selection.  can any one please tell me a solution

```
 public void vesselspinnerHandler(){
    //Setting Class to Spinner

    final ArrayAdapter<String> vesselspinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, vessellist);
    vesselspinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    vesselspinner.setAdapter(vesselspinnerAdapter);
    vesselspinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    final AutoCompleteTextView searchvessel=findViewById(R.id.searchvessel);
    final AutoCompleteTextView selves = findViewById(R.id.selectedvessel);
    ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(selection.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,vessellist);
    selves.setAdapter(adapter1);
    selves.setDropDownVerticalOffset(50);




    vesselspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            selves.setText(vesselspinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
            searchvessel.setText(selves.getText().toString());

            getdate();//second spinner call
            return;

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


        }
    });

 }
```